# Single word describing elevators, escalators and stairs?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm wondering if there is a single word describing *elevators, escalators and stairs*?

The context is when grouping them in a category in a user interface.

Comment: What about "level access" ?

Answer (score 6):

Not a single word, but the architectural term seems to be **"Vertical transportation"**.

From [Wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Building_Services/Vertical_Transportation),

> Vertical transportation is a phrase used to describe the various means of travelling between floors in a building. All buildings with more than one storey of course have at least one set of stairs and the provision of stairs is a very important consideration when designing buildings in order to ensure all the occupants of the building can escape safely in the event of a fire.
>
> In buildings with more than four storeys, a lift (commonly known as an elevator in the US) is desirable as there is a limit to how far people are willing to walk up stairs. In addition to this, stairs are unsuitable for infirm and mobility impaired persons so buildings with only two storeys are sometimes fitted with a lift.
>
> A third option is the escalator which is ideally suited for high volume applications such as shopping malls and airports but not practical for high rise buildings as they take up a lot of space.